Direction of angular momentum
I came across this question in one of my tests:

A bob of mass $m$ is attached to an inextensible string of length $l$ suspended from a vertical support. The bob rotates in a horizontal circle with an angular speed $w$ about the vertical. About the point of suspension:

Angular momentum is conserved.

Angular momentum changes in magnitude but not in direction.

Angular momentum changes in direction but not in magnitude.

Angular momentum changes both in direction and magnitude.



The answer is option 3.
What I don't understand is why does the direction of angular momentum change. I understand about the magnitude but shouldn't the direction remain same as the direction of angular velocity remain constant?

The test question seems to be lacking details, so that there should be no possible answer to it.

@naturallyInconsistent Not true. The origin is specified. This is a standard conceptual example to explain the subtleties of angular momentum.

The reason here is that the origin is taken to be the point of suspension. Suppose we take the $z$-axis as the vertical. The mass is therefore not moving in the $z=0$ plane; it is moving in a plane of negative $z$.
Consider the instant where the mass passes through the $xz$-plane. The velocity at this instant is exactly in the $y$ direction but the position has both nonzero $x$ and nonzero $z$. In the picture, the velocity is into the page.

Therefore, at this instant, there is angular momentum about both the $z$-axis and the $x$-axis. Since the mass moves in a horizontal circle, angular momentum has both a constant vertical component and a horizontal radial component which changes direction with the mass.
The lesson here is that angular momentum depends on the choice of origin. If the origin were moved downward to the same level of the mass, then the angular momentum will indeed have only the constant vertical component.
This is covered in section 9.2.1, examples 1 and 2 of Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics: With Problems and Solutions.

Ohh I get so if the point of rotation was in the same plane as L then direction would be same otherwise it keeps changing. Can you also pls clarify that the vector of angular momentum starts from the point of rotation (origin) or from where the mass is? Thanks :)

@TanushGupta The starting point of a vector doesn't matter. Vectors are mathematical objects. You can add and subtract them regardless of where you draw them. Even in the case of forces, where the point of application is important, it is still just a convenient choice to draw them there. It is not necessary. They still add to give the net force.

@TanushGupta The mass is moving in a circle. The string is massless and can be ignored. If you choose your $xy$ plane not in the plane of the circle, then the angular momentum will have (time-varying) components about the $x$ and $y$ axes, and these make up the horizontal radial component whose direction rotates with the mass.
